# Why is calling a Slick Slider method returning the object?

Tags: jquery, slick.js

The slick slider itself is working perfectly but when you try to call a method on the slider instance from the console it returns the object rather than performing the action.
E.g.

```js
jQuery('.questions-answers-slider').slick('slickCurrentSlide');
```

Returns:

```
Object { 0: div.questions-answers-slider.slick-initialized.slick-slider, length: 1, prevObject: {…}, context: HTMLDocument *******, selector: ".questions-answers-slider" }
```

I can actually write

```js
jQuery('.questions-answers-slider').slick('ABSOLUTELYANYTHING');
```

and it returns:

```
Object { 0: div.questions-answers-slider.slick-initialized.slick-slider, length: 1, prevObject: {…}, context: HTMLDocument *******, selector: ".questions-answers-slider" }
```

Does anyone know why this is happening. I've tested this Slick method on other slick websites and it works fine. I'm using Slick Slider version 1.8.1.

Comment: Like most jQuery methods, jQuery plugins also return the [`jQuery` object](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) wrapping the selected element(s) for convenient method chaining. When calling functions in the console, the return value is logged. What exactly did you expect to be logged instead?

Comment: It should return the current slide index (as per Slick docs):
slickCurrentSlide
Returns the current slide index